# Problem concatenating URL and scraping data

Tags: python, url

I am trying to append a URL in python to scrape details from the target URL.
I have the below code but it seems to be scraping the data from url1 rather than URL.

I have scraped the team names from the NFL websit without any issue. The issue is with the spotrac URL where I am appending the team name which I have scraped from the NFL website.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   

URL ='https://www.nfl.com/teams/'

page = requests.get(URL)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

team_name = []

team_name_list = soup.find_all('h4',class_='d3-o-media-object__roofline nfl-c-custom-promo__headline')
for team in team_name_list:
  if team.find('p'):
      team_name.append(team.text)

for team in team_name: 
        
    team = team.replace(" ", "-").lower()

    url1 = 'https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/'
    URL = url1 +str(team)
    print(URL)
    data = {
        'ajax': 'true',
        'mobile': 'false'
    }
    
    bs_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(URL, data=data).content, 'html.parser')
    spotrac_df = pd.DataFrame(columns = ['Name', 'Salary']) 
    
    for h3 in bs_soup.select('h3'):
        spotrac_df = spotrac_df.append(pd.DataFrame({'Name': str(h3.text), 'Salary' : str(h3.find_next(class_="rank-value").text)}, index=[0]), ignore_index=False)
```

I'm almost certain the problem is coming from the URL not appending properly. The scraping is taking the salaries etc from url1 rather than URL.

My console output (using Spyder IDE) is as below for print(URL)
[image]

Comment: "How can I append the team name to the URL each time the loop runs?" exactly the way you do it in this code.

Comment: When I continue with some web scraping, it is scraping from url1 for some reason.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show the actual problem you encounter.

Comment: OK - apologies. I was sure it was the URL appending was the problem. 1 minute

Comment: Also read [this article](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: I tried that also Youness but it didn't fix the issue.

Comment: Does `print(URL)` give the URL you expect? Are you sure this URL is actually correct? I mean does it really load the resource you are expecting?

Comment: It gives me the correct URL but the team name is on a new line, which I think might be the problem. I have copied and pasted in to the browser and it is the correct link every time. (e.g. https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/
carolina-panthers - image of console output added to the original question)

Comment: I suggest doing this: `team_name.append(team.text.strip())`. Now you avoid any extra whitespace.

Comment: when I visit https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings and inspect the page, I see there is a `<form>` for searching. I suggest you emulate the form for your `post()` request in order to get it right.

Comment: What I did was set the team name to be one of the teams, updated and mimicked that URL. Is my approach wrong? I am brand-new to web scraping so appreciate your help very much by the way!

Comment: team.text.strip() has fixed the issue! If you want to add it as an answer, I will mark it as the solution! Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

url is appending correctly, but you have a leading white space in your team names. I also made a few other changes and noted them in the code.

Lastly, (and I used to do this two), creating an empty dataframe then appending to it after each iteration I suppose isn't the best method. I've been told it better to construct your rows using lists/dictionaries, and then when done, then call on pandas to construct the dataframe, so changed that as well.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup   
import pandas as pd

url ='https://www.nfl.com/teams/'

page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

team_name = []

team_name_list = soup.find_all('h4',class_='d3-o-media-object__roofline nfl-c-custom-promo__headline')
for team in team_name_list:
  if team.find('p'):
      team_name.append(team.text.strip()) #<- remove leading/trailing white space

url1 = 'https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/' #<- since this is fixed, put it before the loop
spotrac_rows = []
for team in team_name: 
        
    team = '-'.join(team.split()).lower() #<- changed to split in case theres 2 spaces between city and team

    url1 = 'https://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/'
    url = url1 + str(team)
    print(url)
    data = {
        'ajax': 'true',
        'mobile': 'false'
    }
    
    bs_soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.post(url, data=data).content, 'html.parser')
    
    for h3 in bs_soup.select('h3'):
        spotrac_rows.append({'Name': str(h3.text), 'Salary' : str(h3.find_next(class_="rank-value").text.strip())})  #<- remove white space from the salary
        
spotrac_df = pd.DataFrame(spotrac_rows)
```

**Output:**

```
print(spotrac_df)
                       Name       Salary
0            Chandler Jones  $21,333,333
1          Patrick Peterson  $13,184,588
2            D.J. Humphries  $12,800,000
3           DeAndre Hopkins  $12,500,000
4          Larry Fitzgerald  $11,750,000
5              Jordan Hicks  $10,500,000
6               Justin Pugh  $10,500,000
7              Kenyan Drake   $8,483,000
8              Kyler Murray   $8,080,601
9             Robert Alford   $7,500,000
10              J.R. Sweezy   $6,500,000
11             Corey Peters   $4,437,500
12           Haason Reddick   $4,288,444
13          Jordan Phillips   $4,000,000
14           Isaiah Simmons   $3,757,101
15            Maxx Williams   $3,400,000
16            Zane Gonzalez   $3,259,000
17            Devon Kennard   $2,500,000
18              Budda Baker   $2,173,184
19       De'Vondre Campbell   $2,000,000
20                 Andy Lee   $2,000,000
21             Byron Murphy   $1,815,795
22           Christian Kirk   $1,607,691
23             Aaron Brewer   $1,168,750
24               Max Garcia   $1,143,125
25            Andy Isabella   $1,052,244
26               Mason Cole     $977,629
27               Zach Allen     $975,855
28              Chris Banjo     $887,500
29         Jonathan Bullard     $887,500
                    ...          ...
2530       Khari Blasingame     $675,000
2531         Kenneth Durden     $675,000
2532         Cody Hollister     $675,000
2533              Joey Ivie     $675,000
2534            Greg Joseph     $675,000
2535             Kareem Orr     $675,000
2536     David Quessenberry     $675,000
2537        Derick Roberson     $675,000
2538           Shaun Wilson     $675,000
2539          Cole McDonald     $635,421
2540          Chris Jackson     $629,570
2541             Kobe Smith     $614,333
2542           Aaron Brewer     $613,333
2543           Cale Garrett     $613,333
2544           Tommy Hudson     $613,333
2545     Kristian Wilkerson     $613,333
2546  Khaylan Kearse-Thomas     $612,500
2547         Nick Westbrook     $612,333
2548          Kyle Williams     $611,833
2549           Mason Kinsey     $611,666
2550          Tucker McCann     $611,666
2551       Cameron Scarlett     $611,666
2552             Teair Tart     $611,666
2553           Brandon Kemp     $611,333
2554              Wyatt Ray     $610,000
2555             Josh Smith     $610,000
2556         Logan Woodside     $610,000
2557          Rashard Davis     $610,000
2558          Avery Gennesy     $610,000
2559           Parker Hesse     $610,000

[2560 rows x 2 columns]
```